# Appstoreconnect Api user update

Tags: api

I can’t understand how to create the http body of the **Modify User Account** api:

PATCH 
https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users/{id}

In particular the:

[UserUpdateRequest.Data.Relationships.VisibleApps.Data]

What are the required id and type properties of Data object? Could somebody provide a code or postman example of a request ?

This is the url of the topic:

[Appstoreconnect Api - Update User](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/modify_a_user_account)

Comment: I've understood, the app Id is the 10 digit's one in the AppstoreConnect app page: it's called Apple Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PATCH request should look like this:

```
PATCH /v1/users/XXX
{
  "data": {
    "type": "users",
    "id": "XXX",
    "attributes": {
      "allAppsVisible": false
    },
    "relationships": {
      "visibleApps": {
        "data": [
          {"type": "apps", "id": "AAA"},
          {"type": "apps", "id": "BBB"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where AAA and BBB are Apple IDs of your apps. You can find these on the App Information page, or in response to the `/v1/apps` API calls.